# Turning on Start Mode to Always Running in MVC Application without access to Application Pools

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool

I am hosting my website on a server that I don't have access to Application Pools. My site has got only very few users so it shut down, and when someone tries to get in - it takes hella lot of time. So I want to change Start Mode to AlwaysRunning and Preload Enabled set as True and disable timeout/periodic recycling, but I dont have Application Pool in ISS manager (server provider lets me use remote iis).

What can I do? This is my webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken=""/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken=""/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken=""/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken=""/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken=""/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken=""/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to your web site, such as being able to change ApplicationHost.config and your hosting provider does not expose that in a control panel, then there is nothing you can do to do that.
However, one thing you could do is use a "Website ping service" that can ping your website every 5 minutes or so, depending on how often your hosting provider recycles the pool (idle timeout) to prevent it from ever shutting down (of course that might not make your hosting provider happy and they might even block the traffic).

Just bing "website ping service" and you'll find many free ones. If you are using Azure you could use the Web site availability service which does that and also gives you nice metrics and pings it from several places in the world.